# Struct Array storing garbage upon declaration

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am creating an array of 50 structs like so, and reading it into a binary file. When I then try to print it, the struct appear empty for the first 24 elements, but start behaving strangely (printing garbage) afterwards. I would like the ID to be 0, in particular, as I will most likely be using it for testing. Short of reducing the size of my struct, I'm dumbfounded.

I am creating the binary file like so:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct record
{
   int id;
   char name[40];
   char email[50];
   char course[10];
   int grade;
};

int main ();
{
    struct record tempadd[50];
    FILE *in = fopen("records.bin", "ab");
    fwrite(tempadd, sizeof(tempadd), 1, in);
    fclose(in);
}
```

---

I'm printing the record with this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct record
{
   int id;
   char name[40];
   char email[50];
   char course[10];
   int grade;
};

int main ()
{
    struct record record[50];
    FILE *in = fopen("records.bin", "rb");
    fread(record, sizeof(record), 1, in);

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
       printf("Student ID: %d    ", record[i].id);
       printf("Name: %s    ", record[i].name);
       printf("Email: %s    ", record[i].email);
       printf("Course: %s    ", record[i].course);
       printf("Grade: %d\n", record[i].grade);
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

I expect 50 lines of:

```
Student I: 0    Name:     Email:     Course:     Grade: 0
```

Instead, I see many garbage lines like:

```
Student ID: 1724372348    Name: =     Email: =     Course:     Grade:
```

Comment: Your first program writes 50 garbage structs to the file, your second program reads the file and you are surprised to read garbage?   You say 'I would like the ID to be 0"  - you have to include code that sets ID to 0 before writing it, if that is what you want

Comment: If you want the entire structure to be initialized to 0, you can declare `tempadd` as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The code where you create the file has a issue:

`tempadd[50]` is not initialized, either declare it as global or initialize it with the values you required. e.g. If you want `Name` to be empty , you can do `tempadd[0].name = ""`.
Make sure you initialize all array elements.

You can also use `memcpy` to clear all elements of `tempadd`.